# Multiple directives [arValidations, datepickerPopup] asking for new/isolated scope on

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I got the following error when trying to combine my custom directive with a datepicker:

```
Multiple directives [arValidations, datepickerPopup] asking for new/isolated scope on...
```

So I guess I need to remove the isolated scope, the problem is that I don't know how. Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('arValidations', [ 'BaseValidator', '$injector', function(BaseValidator, $injector){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { arValidations: '@?' },
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){

      scope.validations = JSON.parse(scope.arValidations);
      scope.Validator = $injector.get(scope.validations.validator);
      scope.pristine = true;

      scope.BaseValidator = BaseValidator;
      scope.$watch(function(){ return ngModel.$modelValue }, function (attr) {

        var label = scope.validations["attribute"];
        var types = scope.Validator.attributes[label].types;
        var validated = scope.BaseValidator.validateValue(types, attr);

        scope.Validator.attributes[label].valid = validated === true && scope.pristine === false;
        scope.Validator.allValid = scope.BaseValidator.updateAllValidations(scope.Validator.attributes);

        scope.pristine = false;

        if(scope.Validator.attributes[label].valid){
          element.removeClass('valid-input');
          element.addClass('valid-input');
        } else{
          element.removeClass('valid-input');
        }
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

The main issue is that I am injecting a different service in each instance of that directive. Any suggestions?

Edit: I said it several times in the comments but obtaining the `arValidations`  attribute using `attrs` instead of isolating the scope does NOT provide the same functionality because **several instances of the same directive can be created within the same scope** which overwrites the content of `scope.Validator`.

The solution was to separate the 2 directives into several elements to preserve the scope isolation. So here is my homework for today:

Directive:

```
app.directive('validatedDatepicker',  function(){
  return {
    templateUrl: 'directives/validated_datepicker.html',
    scope: { modelInstance: '=validatedDatepicker', modelAttribute: '@?', placeholder: '@?', maxDate: '=?' },
    controller: ['$scope', 'BaseValidator', '$injector', function($scope, BaseValidator, $injector){
      $scope.cssClass = { 'valid-input':  false };
      $scope.Validator = $injector.get($scope.modelInstance.$validator);
      $scope.pristine = true;

      $scope.BaseValidator = BaseValidator;
      $scope.calendarDisplay = false;

      $scope.openDate = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $scope.calendarDisplay = true;
      };

      $scope.$watch(function(){ return $scope.modelInstance[$scope.modelAttribute]; }, function (attr) {

        var label = $scope.modelAttribute;
        var types = $scope.Validator.attributes[label].types;

        var validated = $scope.BaseValidator.validateValue(types, attr);

        $scope.Validator.attributes[label].valid = validated === true && $scope.pristine === false;
        $scope.Validator.allValid = $scope.BaseValidator.updateAllValidations($scope.Validator.attributes);

        $scope.pristine = false;

        if($scope.Validator.attributes[label].valid){
          $scope.cssClass = { 'valid-input':  true };

        } else{
          $scope.cssClass = { 'valid-input':  false };
        }
      });
    }]
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<input placeholder="{{placeholder}}" ng-class="cssClass" type="text" show-button-bar="false" class="form-control required-input" datepicker-popup="dd-MM-yyyy" data-ng-model="modelInstance[modelAttribute]" max-date="modelInstance[maxDate]" is-open="calendarDisplay" close-text="Close"/>
<div class="input-group-addon" data-ng-click="openDate($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
```

EDIT 2: For completeness, `scope: true` will give the same error as `scope: {}`.

Comment: Probably need to remove scope: { arValidations: '@?' }, but then you might need to use attrs to get hold of arValidations

Comment: @Neil, that won't do, I have multiple instances of that directive.

Answer (score 0):

If `arValidations` is supposed to live with other directives on the same elements (and I suppose it is the case), then it should *not* create an isolated scope, and instead share the same scope with these other directives.

So you want to remove the line `scope: { arValidations: '@?' }`

However now you need to implement this `@` binding manually the regular way, which is by adding, in your `link` function:

```
attrs.$observe('arValidations', function(value) {
  scope.arValidations = value;
});
```

This way everytime the `{{}}` interpolated binding is updated, your scope will be updated.

**UPDATE** For your direcitve to have its own scope, but still inherited and not isolated, you need to add `scope: true` to the directive:

```
restrict: 'A',
scope: true,
require: '?ngModel',
link: ....
```

Comment: if it was as easy as geting the element attribute, I would have done it. The problem is with the $injector overwriting the `scope.Validator` on each instance of that directive.

Comment: By the way, I don't need to observe arValidations, it is just an initializer.

Comment: If that's just an initializer indeed you don't need `$observe` nor the `@` binding you currently have. Simply do `$parse(attrs. arValidations)(scope)` (or even simpler `scope.$eval(attrs.arValidations)` ). I don't understand your problem though. `scope.Validator`doesn't exist initially so you need to define it on every instance of that directive don't you?

Comment: Validator is not always the same object, if I dont create a new scope, it's gonna be initialized to whichever value the last directive instance is set to. I found a workaroud though, I have to set a container directive that includes the input in its template, I just do that for the datepicker though.

Comment: I don't see how the "last directive" would have any effect on the current one. `scope.Validator` is set by `scope.arValidations` which is parsed and unique by directive. In case it helps, if you want something to be shared accross the directives instances you should use a `service`.

Comment: You are assuming the directive creates a child scope.

Comment: @AlexC, this answer gives you what you would have achieved with an isolate scope and `"@"` bound variable. If you have further requirements/constraints, please edit the original question and explain what they are. (It's also not clear why you have all this validation logic, when validation is built-in into `ngModel` and `form` directives)

Comment: @New Dev, If you read the title, you will notice that having an isolate/new scope is the opposite of my requirement. The answer above is also the first thing I tried before posting on stackoverflow. I ll update my post and submit my own workaround, I am not using the built in validations because I dont like them and I am also not using the form tag.

Comment: @AlexC, I understood your question - you need the equivalent functionality of what a one-way string binding would have given you, which this answer provides.

Comment: @AlexC sorry I indeed forgot something, which is create a new child scope but *not isolated*, so every directive still has its own scope (and then don't share `scope.Validator `). I have updated my answer.